# Upload large video file in Django asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

For one of the projects I need to upload a large video file(>1GB) to Django server.

```
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
```

Issue is, it is taking a long time. In production this will cause error as it will be a bad user experience and secondly it will throw error with nginx server more than 30 sec.

Is there any way to upload the file to the server asynchronously using the same model...??